# I can not run Windows apps without Internet

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, appx, windows-terminal

My work computer doesn't have a network connection.
But I need to install specific **appx**s.

1. I installed [*Windows Terminal*](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases) from `.msixbundle` file.
2. I installed [*Ubuntu 20.04*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) (WSL distro) from `.appx` file.

*They were downloaded and moved to my pc from another pc with internet connection.*

When I run one of them an error occurs:

> We want to make sure this is you. User interaction is required for authentication.

Or

> The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.

What does it mean? What do I need to do in order to run those apps without internet connection?

Comment: This question seems off-topic for SO. You will certainly have a hard time coming up with a [mre] for this one. Microsoft does have its own support forums somewhere. Maybe try those?

Comment: This means that Microsoft wants to gather as much information about everyone as they can possibly get away with.